# Block element's background image goes behind float element

Tags: html, css, css-float, background-image

I have a slight problem with a background image on a block element that is preceded by a floating element.

I float an image to the left, followed by a `H1`. As expected, the `H1` (which is a blocl-level element) flows behind the image, but it's contents (the actual title) appear to the right of the image.

Unfortunately, the background-image I'm using on the `H1` has to be aligned to the left, and thus appears behind the actual `img`, because unlike the contents this is not pushed by the floating behaviour.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/WwuqG/

(I set the second title to `clear: left` to show what it should look like).

One solution is to set the left-margin of the title to a little more than the floating image's width, but that would require me to know it's width beforehand.

Another option is adding the title's icon in an element inside the `h1`, but that's not semantically correct.

Is there a better css-only solution that doesn't require additional elements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

add `overflow:hidden` to the `h1`

new **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WwuqG/4/)**

Answer (score 2):

I'm slightly confused.

If I do what you suggested:

> set the left-margin of the title to a
>   little more than the floating image's
>   width

It looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/WwuqG/1/

My confusion comes from the fact that your problem seems to be.. really simple to fix.

- Also add `float: left` to the `<h1>`: http://jsfiddle.net/WwuqG/2/

This works with whatever `width` image: http://jsfiddle.net/WwuqG/3/

Is that it, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: The first one, with the margin-left, is ok. Unfortunately I don't know the width of the image, so I'd have to set the margin with javascript afterwards.
Your second answer works fine, except that there's more elements below the `h1` that have to appear below it, but right of the image. By floating the `h1` they will show up to the right of the `h1`. I cannot clear them because then they'll appear below the image. Sorry if my queston was incomplete